# Converting the entries of an m x n array to a list

Tags: vba

for an accounting export file, I am trying to create a list of amounts out of an m x n array (see pic 1 at bottom). The goal is to create an entry for each amount entered in B10:K27. This entry should also contain its corresponding codes line 9 and column A respectively.
[image]

So the output row (cells A1:C1) in the export-sheet for the entry in C7 should be:

4,00 ; 219 ; 12350

The problem: I managed to define the range and to get the actual amounts into my export-list but whatever I tried, I don't know how to "select" the current applicable row and applicable column for the value that is currently being processed via "For Each importcell In importrange.cells" so I can paste it. This is my current code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub AddToImportSheet()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long
Dim importrange As Range
Dim importcell As Range
Dim outputrange As Range
Dim outputrow As Long
Dim outputcol As Long

lastrow = Sheet1.Range("A9").End(xlDown).Row
lastcol = Sheet1.Cells(9, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Set importrange = Sheet1.Range(Sheet1.Cells(9 + 1, 1 + 1), Sheet1.Cells(lastrow, lastcol))

outputrow = 1
outputcol = 1

Set outputrange = Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(outputrow, outputcol), Sheet2.Cells(outputrow, outputcol))

For Each importcell In importrange.Cells
    If importcell <> 0 And IsNumeric(importcell) = True Then
        Sheet2.Range(Sheet2.Cells(outputrow, outputcol), Sheet2.Cells(outputrow, outputcol)) = importcell.Value
        outputrow = outputrow + 1
    Else
    End If
Next importcell

End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thank you.

[Input-Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBYeg.png)

Comment: wouldn't a pivot table solve your problem?

Comment: Apart from me never having tried to combine VBA with a pivot table I don't know if that's a solution. The final sheet is supposed to be used by multiple people, and manual tasks like repeatedly having to adjust the pivot table range are not an option. Also, i intend to add some buttons like "Add entries to current export-sheet", "Clear export-sheet and add" and so on...

Comment: So the goal is to create an export-file that's as user-friendly as possible. Put your stuff in range A9:whatever, press button to "clear & add" or "add to existing" and press button to save as CSV afterwards. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

The code below should just about do the job. Please try it.

```
Sub AppendToExportSheet()
    ' 160
    
    Dim SrcRng          As Range                ' soure data range
    Dim Src             As Variant              ' Source data
    Dim C               As Long                 ' loop counter: columns
    Dim R               As Long                 ' loop counter: rows
    Dim Output          As Variant              ' data of one row
    Dim Ro              As Long                 ' target row for Output
    
    With Sheet1
        Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(9, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
        ' the column title is 0                 ' change to suit
        Set SrcRng = SrcRng.Find(0, , xlValues, xlWhole)
        If (SrcRng Is Nothing) Or (SrcRng.Column = 1) Then
            MsgBox "Subtotal column not found.", vbInformation, "Programming error"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Set SrcRng = .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)) _
                            .Resize(, SrcRng.Column)
        Src = SrcRng.Value
        ' Debug.Print SrcRng.Address
    End With
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False          ' less work: run faster
    With Sheet2
        Ro = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For R = 1 To UBound(Src)
            If Val(Src(R, UBound(Src, 2))) Then ' if subtotal has a value <> 0
                ReDim Output(1 To 3)
                Output(1) = Src(R, UBound(Src, 2))
                Output(3) = Src(R, 1)
                For C = 2 To UBound(Src, 2)
                    If Val(Src(R, C)) Then
                        Output(2) = Src(1, C)
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next C
                Ro = Ro + 1
                .Cells(Ro, 1).Resize(1, UBound(Output)).Value = Output
            End If
        Next R
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

The code examines the subtotal column and creates an entry if there is a value. This method has a number of implications. First, it finds the column by searching for a header `0`. Change the criterium if it isn't 0 in real life. Second, it ignores any data in the section "Commission 2". Extracting data from there wasn't part of your question here but to add data from there would just need to reconfigure the `SrcRng` at the beginning and then loop through the sections in the second part of the code.

Comment: Thanks, man. Much appreciated. Your code works, although I don't understand what you did (and that kinda bothers me because I'm trying to learn). I suppose I also could've described my problem more clearly. I added the zeros in cells A9 and F9 to easily exclude columns and to get the range selected properly. So my suggested solution was "get range starting at A9 to bottom right, and for each numeric value /= 0 in range make said three entries". So that it even works if the subtotal columns were deleted.

Comment: I think you got it the other way around by creating entries when the subtotal of a row isn't zero? Not sure, though. Also, is there a solution for my initial approach of getting the current column and row from the respective importcell? I can see that the values for row and column are stored as long (in the "Locals" window).